# Yammer login SSO without embedfeed

Tags: single-sign-on, yammer

We are embedding a Yammer feed on a web page with SSO enabled (use_sso: true). This is working correctly. We also need to use the Yammer API to retrieve extra Yammer information like comments. Therefore we have 2 options:

1. Embed the Yammer feed with SSO. After login, retrieve comments. This will only work after a refresh of the page, because the SSO cookie is only set for the embedfeed iframe.
2. Login to Yammer via the API, with yam.platform.login and a custom Login button. After login, retrieve comments and embed the feed.

Scenario 1 is confusing for the users. They won't have comments on first pageload.
Scenario 2 is working, but we can't get SSO to work.

Question: How can we use SSO with yam.platform.login, or whatelse can we do?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`yam.platform.login` works regardless of SSO or not. The user's home network configuration determines the sorta authentication method to use. That said, Embed is not designed to be customizable or used along side with the REST API. So it's either you use just embed as is, or build your own custom UI with the REST API.

Comment: Is there currently a way to get O365 / Yammer SSO working using the REST API? Using yam.platform.login does not authenticate the user, even after signing in to Office 365.